# get input from windows application

Tags: opengl, mfc, windows

I am developing a windows application to render a scene using OpenGL. my application is of that type with

```
int WINAPI  WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
```

and I am calling opengl rendering functions somewhere down in the program.
I struggle a lot to render my openGL scene inside a frame in application but I had so much pain to change my WinMain application into a form like GUI application. I know how people do it regularly but my program has different structure and it uses different camera classes and so on, so that you cannot simply use glut like structure.I even used QT but there the problem was that my libraries uses MultiByteCharacterSet and Qt uses unicode by default and got problems.

at the end I decided to not change my program to one that have GUI and continue with just a window in full screen (like game) or windowed without buttons or menus (i even tried MFC).

but now i need to get some text input from the user, lets say I want to get a name for a "file" that i am going to save. i dont have a window or text box for this and I dont have Console window already.
how it is possible to do that ? is it possible to use console ? (this is window application, but I saw some apps that although they are rendering into a window they have also console window).
or how can I just have a text box for input that pop up when user hit R (record) button on the keyboard.any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use common dialogs for input, for example the [`Save As`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) dialog.

Comment: thank you, i handle to do that with this common dialog. could you offer a solution to address what i explained about my application? the GUI stuff

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking. Are you trying to run windowed?

Comment: yes what i am trying to do is to render my opengl stuff inside a dialog while i have a dialog with buttons,menus etc. i tried different approaches as i said (using Qt or trying to add MFC dialogs) but no success so far

Comment: I think you should split them into two separate questions. I have never used anything other than pure WinAPI for OpenGL.